# Listar categorias de um custom post

Tags: wordpress

Eu tenho um Custom post chamado 'projects'.
Em determinadas paginas eu preciso exibir apenas os 'projects' que tiverem a categoria 'apps'. Até ai tudo bem, ele exibe numa boa.
Porém, quando eu adiciono tags nesse project, eu nao consigo listar apenas as tags desse determinado post. Assim tbm como nao consigo listar todas as categorias que o post contem. No codigo abaixo ele retorna todas as categorias, todas, inclusive as que nao estao ligadas ao post

```
<?php
      query_posts(
        array(
          'post_type' => 'projects',
          'category_name' => 'apps',
          'showposts' => 3,
          'orderby' => 'date'
          )
        );
?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
       $categories = get_categories($postID);
       var_dump($categories);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`wp_get_object_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) para resgatar tanto as *tags* quanto as *categories*, visto que ambos são [`taxonomias`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies). De maneira minimalista, é possível fazer

```
<?php

    if(have_posts()){
        while(have_posts()){
            the_post();

            $tags = wp_get_object_terms( $postID , 'post_tag' );

            var_dump($tags);

            $categories = wp_get_object_terms( $postID , 'category' );

            var_dump($categories);
        }
    }
```

Para efeitos de curiosidade, o seu uso do método [`get_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) está incorreto. Ele retorna uma lista de objetos de categoria (por isso o erro que você encontra), e não recebe o `$postID` como argumento.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, eu usei esse mesmo deveria ter vindo aqui e fechado o post, mas foi isso mesmo.
Valeus